# What is the counterpart of urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode in iOS?

Tags: android, ios, objective-c, post

I'm developing iOS app which is already developed for android. I have a problem with sending some data to server with post request. I can send it but server returns error. Developer of android version said that I need to use urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode(bytes.length). But I can't find a counterpart for this on iOS. So, is there any counterpart for urlConnection.setFixedLengthStreamingMode on iOS?

Here is an example of my request:

```
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:self.urlSessionConfiguration];
    urlString = [urlString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    NSData *body = [bodyString dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    request.HTTPBody = body;
    request.HTTPMethod = @"POST";

    NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    }];

    [postDataTask resume];
```

Comment: What are you using for network communication? NSURLConnection, NSURLSession, some 3-rd party framework? Post the code you are using for upload.

Comment: Also, from what I understand `setFixedLengthStreamingMode` only optimises internal memory usage, and should not affect actual communication.